# scroll grid sometimes not reload again in extjs

Tags: extjs

i have a grid and scroll in a grid. this is my code for generate the grid

```
gridMain = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.get("sa-grid"),
        store: 'pf-store',
        height: mainContentHeight - 63,
        title: 'Promotion Form',
        columns: [{
            text: 'No PF',
            width: 115,
            dataIndex: 'PFID'
        },
        {
            text: 'Title',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'Title'
        },
        {
            text: 'Promotion From',
            dataIndex: 'PromotionFrom'
        },
        {
            text: 'Promotion To',
            dataIndex: 'PromotionTo'
        },
        {
            text: 'Limit Payment Date',
            width: 120,
            dataIndex: 'LimitPaymentDate'
        },
        {
            text: 'Request Status',
            width: 150,
            dataIndex: 'RequestDescription'
        },
        {
            text: 'Initiator',
            width: 150,
            dataIndex: 'CreateByName'
        }],
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            items: [actAddPF, actEditPF, actDeletePF, actExtendPF]
        }],
        listeners: {
            itemdblclick: function (view, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
                isGridClicked = true;
                ViewDetails(FormState.VIEW);
            }
        }
    });


function ViewDetails(FormState) {
        var data = GetSelectedRecord(gridMain);
        var id = data.PFID;
        ShowLoading("sa-body", "Please Wait ...");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: root + "PF/GetDataByID",
            data: { PFID: id },
            success: function (result) {
                try {
                    DataToArray(result);
                    DataToControl(result);
                    CreatePivotPeriode();
                    CreateMainPivot();
                    ChangeFormState(FormState);
                    tabs.setActiveTab('pageDetails');
                } catch (err) {
                    MsgErr(err);
                }
            },
            complete: function () {
                try {
                    HideLoading();
                } catch (err) {
                    MsgErr(err);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

it works fine, but when i insert or modify data and load again or click search by parameter. the scroll is not working. the content in grid is update based on search parameter, the problem is only the scroll which is not working anymore. then I have to do F5 to refresh it again so the grid can be scroll again.

this is my code for searching in grid

```
   $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
        ShowLoading("sa-body", "Please Wait ...");
        $.post(root + "PF/Search", { FieldName: $("#cbSearch").val(), Pattern: $("#cbPattern").val(), Condition: $("#txtSearch").val() }, function (data) {
            storePF.loadDataViaReader(data);
            HideLoading();
        });
    });
```

Does someone have a solution about this problem ?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can do by this
:)

```
Ext.override(Ext.grid.Scroller, {
    onAdded: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        var me = this;
        if (me.scrollEl) {
            me.mun(me.scrollEl, 'scroll', me.onElScroll, me);
            me.mon(me.scrollEl, 'scroll', me.onElScroll, me);
        }
    }
});
```